# Angular - Updating to Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to update the values in my form. The problem is, I am not sure how to get the firebase key of the table. I have a button which when clicked, will display the values on to the form. The next step is to make the changes and then click on the Update button to save it to Firebase.

I have done this and it works but this is definitely not the solution as it causes issues on the page.

```
 <button *ngFor="let content of educates" id="updateBtn" class="btn btn-light" (click)="Update(content.key)" style="visibility: hidden">Update</button>
```

What is the best way to get the Firebase key?

My component.ts

```
Update(key: string) {

    this.educateSrv.getAll();
    let _educate = new Educate();

    _educate.roles = this.Form.value.roles;
    _educate.widgets = this.Form.value.widgets;
    _educate.url = this.Form.value.url;
    _educate.title = this.Form.value.title;
    _educate.status = this.Form.value.uploadWhen;
    _educate.updatedBy = this.currentUser;
    let _date = new Date()
        .toDateString()
        .replace(/^\S+\s/, '');
    _educate.updatedAt = _date;

    this.educateSrv.Update(key, _educate);
}
```

My service.ts

```
Update(id: string, data:Educate) {
    return this.af.object("/educate/" + id).update(data);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add the code where you are reading data.

Comment: @BalajKhan what do you mean? the Update function in my component.ts is able to get the values entered in my form. The issue is getting the key of the selected item

Comment: When you read data from firebase the key is not present in the data you have to concatenate the key with data.

Comment: @BalajKhan yes. can i know how i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can get key by returning its with data:

```
data: any;

readData() {

   this.db.list('listname').snapshotChanges().pipe(map(list => {
       return list.map(items => {
         return {key: items.payload.key, ...items.payload.val()}
       })
    })).subscribe(data => {
       this.data = data;
       });

}
```